# use mysql SUM() in a WHERE clause between two table

Tags: mysql

```
----------
products
----------
product_id | price 
1          | 5     
1          | 5     
2          | 10    
2          | 10
```

```
----------
warehouse
----------
product_id  | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | store_id
1           |   1  |   0  |  0   |  10
1           |   0  |   0  |  0   |  20
2           |   0  |   0  |  0   |  10
2           |   0  |   0  |  0   |  20
```

How can I select DISTINCT id from products WHERE the SUM of qty1 qty2 qty3 are greater than zero?

Comment: Use `having` it can't be in the `where`. The structure `qtyX` also seems like a bad schema but unclear what those are.

Comment: Why does the product table repeat both ids twice?

Comment: my mistake. I've updated the fields name

Comment: You -still- have product id 1 twice, and product id 2 twice.  Which makes no sense.

Comment: I would start by normalising my products table.

Comment: MatBailie it make no sense in my example but in real life there are many missing fields i omitted; think of those products like vaccines, there's the need to track production batch number and changing buy prices

Answer (score 0):

You exact requirements are very unclear, but this is the kind of syntax you need...

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  warehouse
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  SUM(qty1 + qty2 + qty3) > 0
```

Comment: i need to select the product_id from the table products so I can get the price too

Answer (score 0):

This will work. This will also include the price of it

```
SELECT
  w.id, p.price
FROM
  warehouse w join products p on w.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  SUM(w.qty1 + w.qty2 + w.qty3) > 0
```